# append links with unique number string

Tags: php, theme-development, permalinks

I am in the process of developing a WordPress theme for a news site that delivers the news in bitesized chunks with the story regally updated with new content. What I am having trouble with is this:

Next to each update I would like a number, so the first post will be 1, then the next update will be 2 and so on.

I would also like these numbers to be links with a unique number string at the end of the normal URL so for instance if the URL was `example.com/NSA-hacks-merkels-cell-phone` the second update would be `example.com/NSA-hacks-merkels-cell-phone/123456` so that that update can be easily shared.

Is any of this possible? any help that the community can give me on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are the updates to the original post or new posts? If only updates, maybe you could pull in the revision number and append to the URL? See http://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions

Comment: @TomC the updates will be to existing articles.

Comment: So would that work? mysite.com/NSA-hacks-merkels-cell-phone the second update would be mysite.com/NSA-hacks-merkels-cell-phone/1 (where 1 = Revision No. 1)

Answer (score 0):

you should probably create a CPT with hierarchical structure like pages and support for categories and tags if needed. Once you have it each story can be a "main" page and each update its child. You might need to decide how to generate RSS and email updates for it if it is required.

Another alternative is to base what you do on the P2 theme. What it does is in a way exactly what you want. I think that the main problem there is sharing the update on social networks and you might need to learn how to share html fragments. Main drawback that I can see right now is how do you handle "real" comments, and again RSS and email udates.